# Essential philosophy behind Support Vector Machine

Tags: visualization, multidimensional-array, pca, svm

I am studying Support Vector Machines (SVM) by reading a lot of material. However, it seems that most of it focuses on how to classify the input 2D data by mapping it using several kernels such as linear, polynomial, RBF / Gaussian, etc.

My first question is, can SVM handle high-dimensional (n-D) input data?

According to what I found, the answer is YES!

If my understanding is correct, n-D input data will be

1. constructed in Hilbert hyperspace, then those data will be
2. simplified by using some approaches (such as PCA ?) to combine it together / project it back to 2D plane, so that
3. the kernel methods can map it into an appropriate shape such a line or curve can separate it into distinguish groups.

It means most of the guides / tutorials focus on step (3). But some toolboxes I've checked cannot plot if the input data greater than 2D. How can the data after be projected to 2D?

If there is no projection of data, how can they classify it?

My second question is: is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2):

`My first question is, does SVM can handle high-dimensional (n-D) input data?`

Yes. I have dealt with data where n > 2500 when using LIBSVM software: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/. I used linear and RBF kernels.

`My second question is, does it correct my understanding?`

I'm not entirely sure on what you mean here, so I'll try to comment on what you said most recently. I believe your intuition is generally correct. Data is "constructed" in some n-dimensional space, and a hyperplane of dimension n-1 is used to classify the data into two groups. However, by using kernel methods, it's possible to generate this information using linear methods and not consume all the memory of your computer.

I'm not sure if you've seen this already, but if you haven't, you may be interested in some of the information in this paper: http://pyml.sourceforge.net/doc/howto.pdf. I've copied and pasted a part of the text that may appeal to your thoughts:

> A kernel method is an algorithm that depends on the data only through dot-products. When this is the case, the dot product can be replaced by a kernel function which computes a dot product in some possibly high dimensional feature space. This has two advantages: First, the ability to generate non-linear decision boundaries using methods designed for linear classifiers. Second, the use of kernel functions allows the user to apply a classifier to data that have no obvious fixed-dimensional vector space representation. The prime example of such data in bioinformatics are sequence, either DNA or protein, and protein structure.

It would also help if you could explain what "guides" you are referring to. I don't think I've ever had to project data on a 2-D plane before, and it doesn't make sense to do so anyway for data with a ridiculous amount of dimensions (or "features" as it is called in LIBSVM). Using selected kernel methods should be enough to classify such data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. There are some new points I've learnt from you.

Comment: (1) "Data in n-dimensional space, and a hyperplane of dimension n-1 is used to classify the data into two groups". This is very important thing to me. It means SVM dont reduce the number of dimensions. It just keep it as it is! So I wonder how SVM can do, is there any materials explain how SVM do it, roughly its ideas, not the mathematical expressions?

Comment: (2) SVM, and kernel methods in general, uses dot product to map the data. But why dot product? At the beginning, I thought that using dot product is the way to reduce the dimensions. For e.g, a 4-dimension problem can be mapped as 2-D problem after 2 time applying of dot product. However it seems I got wrong.

Comment: (3) Thanks to the paper you introduce me, but I cant get it. However, the quoted part I've read else where.

Comment: (4) Like I wrote, it seems that most of guides / tutorials / lecture notes illustrate SVM with 2D scatter plots, where they focus on how to classify the points into groups by mapping it using several kernels such as linear, polynomial, RBF / Gaussian, etc. 

My question here is, how can they plot those 2D scatter plots for multi-dimensional problem? What does it mean those 2D scatter plots? Is it the raw input data of the 2D problems only, or it is the intermediate results of an reducing / mapping procedure?

Comment: (5) In case there have no such an "reducing / mapping procedure" in treating with multi-dimensional problem, how can we control the SVM algorithm, or it just completely a black-box? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you can't get the paper? I tried clicking the link and the correct PDF file showed up. Also, the idea is that the dot product is used to create a representation of that hyperplane.

Comment: (Continuing from previous comment...) Also, the dot product is used precisely so that the SVM can "understand" a representation of that hyperplane of degree n-1. The dot product method scales well with data, whereas other kernels (RBF) do not, since they are not linear.

Comment: To answer (4), while I can't be entirely sure how they plotted the data, I'm convinced that it's related with, as you say, a mapping procedure that involves using dot products to transform the data so that it can be represented in a 2-D plane. I generally don't put too much thought into those diagrams because they're used to act as a examples to make it easy to visualize the decision boundary. You may also consider emailing whoever made the guide and ask them about their methodology to plot the data. For instance, in the paper I linked earlier, the scatterplots are due to data with 2 features.